# Can I use the IEEE template and change the BibTeX bibliography style?

Tags: bibtex, templates, ieee-style

I am using the IEEE template and the corresponding BibTeX bibliography style like so:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{refs}
```

But I would like for multiple citations to be in the same bracket such as: [1,2], instead of [1],[2] when using the command `\cite{book1,book2}`.

Is there a way to change the options for the BibTeX bibliographic style only?

Comment: Yes it does thank you